# How do I make a background-image "follow" a div?

Tags: html, css

Before asking this, I've been googling and trying various things myself....I know this can be accomplished, even though I haven't found a solution anywhwere.

This is the site...

http://spiralout.org

Notice the background image on the body is centrally aligned with the center of the logo (at 1440 wide), yet it's fixed when you scroll. That's great.

How do I make this responsive?

Right now, I'm using background-position at the various breakpoints, but it's not a real solution...for example. It's aligned right now at 1440, but go down to 1280 (the lowest width while keeping 4 columns) or further and you can see what I'm talking about. How do I get the background image to "follow" the logo div?

I've tried using percentages for background-position, but the logo is a different width, and inside the container so it's percentage from the left side of the screen will always vary proportionately to the background image.

I've tried using it as a background-image on the logo div but I don't seem to understand why it doesn't overflow to the top or left. Even if this solution worked, I don't get to keep the fixed position.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

I don't care if the cost/benefit of doing this is ridiculous, or if the solution has to be jQuery, etc. I just want to know how to accomplish it for my own sake :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, this is only what it takes me to do it:

```
body 
{
  background-image: url('whatever image');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```